# Generic way to get a specific method at runtime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strategy-pattern

I have the following scenario:

```
class Parser():

    def _parse_human(self, record):
        """returns parsed Human"""
        return

    def _parse_animal(self, record):
        """returns parsed Animal"""
        return

    def _parse_vehicle(self, record):
        """returns parsed Vehicle"""
        return

    def parse_object(self, record):
        """Should select the correct parsing method"""
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Parser()
    record = someObject.get_record()

    parsed_object = parser.parse_object(record)
```

I'd like the `parse_object()` method to lookup and execute the corresponding parsing method, without an explicit if-else statement.

The records passed in hold a field with the database table name, thus I can determine what object it should be parsed to.

Is there a way to get this to work without explicitly mapping the function to the table name string in an if-else statement? My goal is to be able to add entities later on without having to update the if-else statement every time.

Are there any pythonic ways to achieve this? I'm just getting familiar with design patterns and a strategy pattern seems to be a appropriate approach. But I'm not sure this is a Pythonic way of doing things.

Comment: `getattr(self, '_parse_{}'.format(table_name))` in order to get the corresponding method in `parse_object`.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard That looks like it should be an answer

Comment: @DavidZ looking for the right dupe atm. Moses beat me to it!

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Sure, but I don't see how posting a comment that answers the question has anything to do with whether you're looking for a duplicate.